# How can you assign a style sheet to a custom tab in the Experience Profile?

Tags: experience-profile

I note that the out of the box tabs of the Experience Profile reference a custom style sheet.

```html
<link href="/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile/Contact/Details/DetailsTab.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile/Contact/Outcomes/Outcomes.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile/Contact/Overview/OverviewTab.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile/Contact/Channels/ChannelsTab.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

etc., etc.

I would like to assign a style sheet to a custom tab I have added to this page.  Is this possible -- and if so, how?

I am running Sitecore 8.1 Update 2?

Comment: Can't you add the reference to your custom tab? I expect that it has a view if you use SPEAK, and then you can just put it there.

Comment: Through a SubPageCode rendering?

Comment: I mean something like here - https://visionsincode.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/make-a-google-map-speak-component-in-sitecore/ here you have the .cshtml where you can put your stylesheet reference.

Comment: I'm on a train but know the answer. when I get to a spot where I can sit down and bang out an answer I will. we just solved this for ourselves a couple weeks ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Style Sheets are added using SPEAK via Sitecore Rocks in Visual Studio. The point of this answer is not to show you how to install Sitecore Rocks, however, I will should you how to add it.

> #### BEST PRACTICE
>
> In the Below Examples, we are working with SPEAK UI through
> Sitecore Rocks. This is recommended, as Sitecore's Content Editor does
> not support some of the rendering properties that SPEAK UI requires.
> As such, it is default procedure to always use Sitecore Rocks when
> editing SPEAK applications.
>
> **NOTE:** that we are editing the **CORE** database, so publishing is
> not needed here.

#### Step 1 - Find the Experience Profile Contact Page Settings

[image]

#### Step 2 - Add a New Item

[image]

#### Step 3 - Search for **Page-Stylesheet-File**

[image]

Set a name for the style sheet here.

#### Step 4 - Set Path to Style Sheet File and Save your Item

Double click on the new item you created (**TestPanelStyle** in this example)

[image]

> **Note**: That this is the physical path location under your Website Root.

#### Step 5 - Save your CSS File in that Physical Path

#### Step 6 - Reload Your Experience Profile Page

You'll Notice that your custom CSS Page now shows up.

[image]

### Version Differences

#### Sitecore 8.0 - Sitecore 8.1 Update 2

Notice that the CSS files are explicit and numerous in SPEAK Applications, as exampled here:

[image]

#### Sitecore 8.1 Update 3

Update 3 Introduces CSS Minification.  The procedure above to add CSS to your Experience Profile Contact Tab is the same, except the resulting source code is the minified CSS.

[image]